# Does Prying Eyes, Greater provide dark or low-light vision?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e

> This spell functions like prying eyes, except that the eyes can see all things as they actually are, just as if they had true seeing with a range of 120 feet. Thus, they can navigate darkened areas at full normal speed.

And it seems True Seeing can only see through Polymorph, Illusions and other things that try to hide or disguise themselves by magical means. It does not provide the ability to see through the darkness, either magical or not.

Since a greater prying eye can "navigate darkened areas at full normal speed", does it have a hidden effect of unlimited range (or 120 feet) of low-light vision or dark vision? (Since it uses the word "darkened" rather than "dark", I assume it is under a condition where low-light vision can be applied.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## No, but yes

Note the text in the [spell description](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/pryingEyesGreater.htm), "as if they had true seeing". If you check out the True Seeing spell, you will find the text:

> The subject sees through normal and magical darkness[.]

So while having neither Low-Light Vision or Darkvision, the eyes created by the Greater Prying Eyes spell (or the True Seeing spell) can see through (ignore) "normal and magical darkness". [And a lot more](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/trueSeeing.htm):

> You confer on the subject the ability to see all things as they actually are. **The subject sees through normal and magical darkness**, notices secret doors hidden by magic, sees the exact locations of creatures or objects under blur or displacement effects, sees invisible creatures or objects normally, sees through illusions, and sees the true form of polymorphed, changed, or transmuted things. Further, the subject can focus its vision to see into the Ethereal Plane (but not into extradimensional spaces).

[Darkvision](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#darkvision), on the other hand, is defined as:

> Darkvision is the extraordinary ability to see with no light source at all, out to a range specified for the creature. Darkvision is black and white only (colors cannot be discerned). It does not allow characters to see anything that they could not see otherwise—invisible objects are still invisible, and illusions are still visible as what they seem to be. Likewise, darkvision subjects a creature to gaze attacks normally. The presence of light does not spoil darkvision.

So it doesn't allow for color vision - True Seeing, or Greater Prying Eyes, does. Similarly, invisible objects are visible and the eyes created can see through illusions, or even see into the Ethereal Plane.

This is, as defined in the text you quote, with a range of 120 feet.

Comment: Thanks for noting! It seems I completely skipped that line for some reason.